# JsonConvert.SerializeObject failes when having a single quote

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have an object say:

```
public class Comment {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

And whenever I have a single quote in the body (the others vars will never have them)

the following line crashes:

```
return JObject.Parse("{ 'Result' : 'Sucessfull!', 'Comment' : '" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(comment) + "' }");
```

And I'm sure it's on the body, because this only happens when I do something  like this:

```
comment.Body = "testing th's ";
```

and the other values, are dynamicly set, and work for bodies without the single quotes.
any clue why this is happening?

*Note: I need to upgrade the `comment.Body` to support new lines later on if that is relevant*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Comment comment = new Comment()
{
    Body = "testing th's ",
    Author = "Author",
    Id = "007"
 };

 var result = new
 {
  Result = "Sucessfull!",
  Comment = comment
 };

 return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you add the `comment` object to your JSON as plain text? What you try to parse is this string:

```
{ 'Result' : 'Sucessfull!', 'Comment' : '{"Id":null,"Author":null,"Body":"testin
g th's"}' }
```

Obviously, it is not a valid JSON string. All you have to do is to rewrite your code a little bit:

```
return JObject.Parse("{ 'Result' : 'Sucessfull!', 'Comment' : " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(comment) + " }");
```